# Is there an equivalent of "reverie" where one is lost in unpleasant thoughts?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

To say "the noise outside shook her from her reverie" implies she was lost in pleasant daydreams.

What if she was lost in worry or unpleasant thoughts? Is there an equivalent term (single word or short phrase)?

Comment: It's often called _a dark study_ in literature. One may be _lost in reverie_ or _lost in a dark study_. Note that _reverie_ is a mass noun, while the phrase _a dark study_ is an indefinite count nounand requires an indefinite article. Even though _study_ can often be used as a mass noun, even with _lost_: _He was lost in study/his studies._ Of course, in that case it refers to actual studying, not unpleasant thought.

Comment: The expression 'Black Dog' has been used to describe various forms of depression. Churchill used to talk of being overcome with the 'Black Dog'. Try looking at some of Shakespeare's dark sonnets, or plays such as Macbeth. I feel sure you will find something there.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In psychology, what you are describing would be called **rumination**. It is where a depressed person gets caught up in their depressed thoughts. To quote [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumination_%28psychology%29):

> Rumination is defined as the compulsively focused attention on the symptoms of one's distress, and on its possible causes and consequences, as opposed to its solutions.

The part about it being "compulsive" refers to the part about getting stuck.

Answer (score 31):

When I wish to increase my unhappiness, I **brood** on things.
[Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/brood):

> Think deeply about something that makes one unhappy

Comment: +1 So *brooding* for the noun?

Comment: +1 - This is the right answer. Accepted answer is incorrect IMO, as per my comment there.

Comment: @bib "Broodings" would be appropriate in the example sentence: "the noise outside shook her from her broodings"

Answer (score 8):

You might have a look at [dysphoria](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dysphoria?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic).

> **dysphoria** *n.* a state of dissatisfaction, anxiety, restlessness, or fidgeting.

Comment: Dysphoria seems to refer to a general or subconscious state of being, whereas reverie/rumination refer more to one who is actively thinking on pleasant/unpleasant (respectively) matters. It's likely that one who ruminates excessively could be considered to be experiencing dysphoria, but one who is experiencing dysphoria may not necessarily be ruminating at any given moment.

Comment: @Did: I don't see where the OP made any specific request regarding active vs. unprompted thoughts. As it is, you seem to be judging this response by the "standard" of *rumination*, an opinion I don't share.

Answer (score 6):

"Reverie" is usually used for a pleasant state, but it is essentially neutral. The OED quotes this from Washington Irving:

1820   W. Irving Sketch Bk. I. 145   Walking about in a sad reverie,..unconscious of the world around her.

Answer (score 5):

I've usually used "***in a funk***", though now Wiktionary is telling me that that specifically means "to be in a depressed mood" rather than "being caught up or preoccupied with dark thoughts", which is how I've always meant it.

It also tells me it's shortened from "**in a *blue* funk**", which I didn't know, but has a nice consonance with @Malvolio's "in a brown study".

Answer (score 3):

I have always liked *[brown study](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brown_study)*.  It means exactly what you want, but Wiktionary denounces it as "dated".

Time to revive it!

Comment: _Brown study_ is an alternative to _dark_. But note it's also a count noun phrase.

Comment: I had never heard the expression "dark study".  Wiktionary doesn't have it, and Google returns only 22K hits, mostly about ill-lit rooms and scientific studies of darkness.

Comment: I (college educated native US English speaker) have no idea what a "brown study" or "dark study" is other than a room in a large house. I would be totally confused by its use in this context.

Answer (score 3):

I would use *angst*.

It implies a partial loss of control over one’s mood, as does *reverie*, with the opposite mood indicated.

Answer (score 2):

*Doldrums*

- [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/doldrums): a dull, listless, depressed mood; low spirits.
- [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Doldrums):
  A period of depression or unhappy listlessness; a depressed or bored state of mind.
- [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doldrums):
  a spell of listlessness or despondency.

However, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doldrums)
omits the depression/despondency aspect and says just
“the state of boredom, malaise, apathy or lack of interest;
a state of listlessness; ennui, or tedium”.

Answer (score 2):

**Melancholy** - Having a feeling of melancholy; sad and pensive.

"the noise outside shook her from her melancholy"

Comment: This was the word that came to my mind first.

Answer (score 1):

Though it can be a little awkward depending on the context, *[daymare](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/daymare)* is the closest word I know to what you are asking.  It means literally "bad daydream."